# Android "Application is not found on your phone" from launcher ..?

Tags: android, android-intent, manifest, launcher

When I launch my application from eclipse (run), It starts up on my phone or emulator, working... This also puts the app in the appdrawer, however, when I press it it says: "Application is not installed on your phone". This is not because it's just an empty shortcut on my homescreen, it actually shows up in the drawer. I tried removing and reinstalling it, but that didn't help either.
Atached is my AndroidManifest.xml since I suspect the problem coming from there.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  package="my.application.package"
  android:versionCode="1"
  android:versionName="1.0">

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

<application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name" android:permission="android.permission.INTERNET">
    <activity android:name=".UserInteraction" android:permission="android.permission.INTERNET"
              android:label="@string/app_name">

        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".WebViewClass"
              android:label="@string/app_name"/>

</application>
</manifest>
```

Comment: Not sure it's the reason, but remove the permissions from the `application` and `activity` nodes, they are not needed there.

Answer (score 3):

@MByD is spot on, but it's not just "not needed" but "actively causing you problems". Get rid of the `android:permission` attributes. You are saying that the launcher has to hold the `INTERNET` permission to launch your app, and the launcher probably does not have that permission.

Comment: Ah great it worked. I thought every part(activity,application) should have that permission declared. Appears it doesn't :) Thanks to both of you !

Comment: @CommonsWare - can you look into this I have similar problem http://stackoverflow.com/q/26553635/3857586